# EclipseLink MOXy @XmlPath support for element with different values e.g. <Pty ID="ID1" Src="6" R="1">

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

Can some one help me to generate `<Pty ID="ID1" Src="6" R="1">` tag using

EclipseLink MOXy `@XmlPath` in single annotation.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you update your question to include what your domain model looks like?

Comment: I need to generate FIXML using EclipseLink MOXy `@XmlPath` as shown below.

System have only ID value based on ID value in single tag, 
i  need to set default value for Src and R attributes.

`
<Pty ID="ID1" Src="6" R="1">
    <Sub ID="ID1" Typ="1" />
    <Sub ID="ID2" Typ="4000" />
    <Sub ID="ID3" Typ="2" />
  </Pty>
  <Pty ID="ID2" Src="1" R="2">
    <Sub ID="ID4" Typ="79228162514264337593543950335" />
    <Sub ID="ID5" Typ="3" />
    <Sub ID="ID6" Typ="4001" />
  </Pty>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have your requirements right, but here is an answer to what I think you are trying to do.

**IdAdapter**

You could write an `XmlAdapter` to convert the single id value into a object with multiple properties.  These other properties would be set with default values.

```
package forum11965153;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class IdAdapter extends XmlAdapter<IdAdapter.AdaptedId, String> {

    public static class AdaptedId {
        @XmlAttribute(name="ID") public String id;
        @XmlAttribute(name="Src") public String src = "6";
        @XmlAttribute(name="R") public String r = "1";
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedId marshal(String string) throws Exception {
        AdaptedId adaptedId = new AdaptedId();
        adaptedId.id = string;
        return adaptedId;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(AdaptedId adaptedId) throws Exception {
        return adaptedId.id;
    }
}
```

**Pty**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to specify the `XmlAdapter`.  To have the values folded into the root element, MOXy's `@XmlPath(".")` annotation is used (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html).

```
package forum11965153;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="Pty")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Pty {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IdAdapter.class)
    @XmlPath(".")
    String id;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

As you know, to specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/jaxb.properties)

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

The following demo code can be used to prove that everything works:

```
package forum11965153;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Pty.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<Pty ID='ID1' Src='6' R='1'/>");
        Pty pty = (Pty) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(pty, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pty ID="ID1" Src="6" R="1"/>
```

Comment: many thanks for your help. <ExecRpt OrdID="OrdID1" OrdID2="OrdID21" ID2="ID21" ExecID2="ExecID21" ID="ID1" OrigID="OrigID1" LnkID="LnkID1" RspID="RspID1" StatReqID="StatReqID1" MassStatReqID="MassStatReqID1" MxPxLvls="1" MaxFloor="1" PosEfct="C" MaxShow="1"   <Pty ID="ID2" Src="1" R="2">
    <Sub ID="ID4" Typ="79228162514264337593543950335" />
    <Sub ID="ID5" Typ="3" />
    <Sub ID="ID6" Typ="4001" />
  </Pty>
  <Pty ID="ID3" Src="I" R="3">
    <Sub ID="ID7" Typ="4" />
    <Sub ID="ID8" Typ="79228162514264337593543950334" />
    <Sub ID="ID9" Typ="5" />
  </Pty> </ExecRpt>

Comment: i have mutilevel/hirarchial tags. i would like to know is there any possibility to generate '<Pty ID="ID3" Src="I" R="3">' in a single tag. @XmlPath("ExecRpt/Pty/@ID") in the same tag i would like to  inject src and R in the same tag.